# Generate lowest possible number from array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shuffle

Let's say I have an array with some numbers, ordered from the lowest to the highest numeral:

```
root@blubb:~# min=1
root@blubb:~# echo $array 
1 2 3 6 16 26 27
```

I want a bash script to always try the minimum number defined first (in this case min=1) and if that is not possible add 1 and try it again, until it finally works (in this case it would take 4)

I tried a lot with `shuf` and while-/for loops but could not get it to run properly.

Comment: It's unclear from the above, what "*lowest possible*" and "*it finally works*" means here.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
min=1
array="1 2 3 6 16 26 27"

found=0
res=$min
for elem in $array; do
    if [[ $elem = $res ]]; then 
        found=1
        continue
    fi
    if [[ $found = 1 ]]; then
       ((res+=1))
       if ((elem>res)); then
           break
       fi
    fi
done

echo $res
```

Or with a function

```
function min_array {
    local min array res found
    min=$1
    shift
    array=$*

    found=0
    res=$min
    for elem in $array; do
        if [[ $elem = $res ]]; then
            found=1
            continue
        fi
        if [[ $found = 1 ]]; then
            ((res+=1))
            if ((elem>res)); then
                break
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo $res
}

$ min_array 1 1 2 3 6 16 26
4

$ min_array 6 1 2 3 6 16 26
7

$ min_array 8 1 2 3 6 16 26
8
```

EDIT one case was missing, another version

```
function min_array {
    local min array res found
    min=$1
    shift
    array=$*

    found=0
    res=$min
    for elem in $array; do
        if [[ $elem = $res ]]; then
            found=1
            ((res+=1))
            continue
        fi
        if [[ $found = 1 ]]; then
            if ((elem>res)); then
                break
            else
                ((res+=1))
            fi
        fi
    done
    echo $res
}
```

Comment: it works as long as the array misses 1 number in between... as soon as the array looks like `array="1 2 3 4 5"` it will print `5` instead of 6... any suggestions?

Comment: yes the function was not working in that case, see last version

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
array=(7 5 3 1)

min()
{
  local min=$1; shift
  local n
  for n in "$@"; do
    if ((n<min)); then
      min=$n
    fi
  done
  echo "$min"
}

min "${array[@]}"
```

Comment: That just outputs the same array with all of its numbers and does not do anything. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: @Permittivity On my system it prints 1.

Comment: @Permittivity, on my system it only outputs "*1*", not as you claim, an array.

Comment: @Permittivity I think the problem is, that you talk about arrays, but do not use arrays.

Comment: Well, we do use arrays, see Nahuels answer: `array="1 2 3 6 16 26 27"`

Comment: @Permittivity That is no array. That is a variable called array containing a string. Take a look at the Bash manual: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Comment: @Permittivity, In `bash` the term "*array*" refers to a specific `bash` data structure.  A list in the general sense would of course be an array, but not with reference to `bash`.